# How to call a future method from a batch class?

Tags: batch

How can I solve this problem? Can you please give me an example or an idea for a potential solution?

Comment: [This](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57154/calling-future-method-from-batch-class) SFSE thread may help you. Please check.

Comment: Or this thread : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24843/calling-future-method-from-batch/24853#24853

Answer (score 0):

If you try to invoke a future method from Batch/Future you will get the below error -

**FATAL ERROR: Future method cant be called from future or Batch**

But noteworthy point here is each **execute** method of batch apex is executed in asynchronously using its own resources and governor limits as an **@future** methods. So I would suggest you to give a try by putting logic in **execute()** method

Reference - https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/194/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_async_processing.pdf

Comment: How do you find more official resources like that pdf?

Answer (score 0):

You can`t call future methods from Batch context.

I believe that workarounds for this depends on why you are using future methods in your code.

If you need to do a callout then you can remove `@future` annotation and do it directly from your Batch but you might want to reduce Batch size because of [limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm). Also reducing Batch size might help if you are using @future to have more resources for some methods.

If your Batch is triggering some code that does `future` calls you might want to add conditions to that code like

```
if(System.isFuture() || System.isBatch()){
    //Your logic here
} else {
    //Mark records with some NeedToProcess__c = true; and then process them in another Batch 
    //moving future logic to that Batch. Or just move your future logic to your Batch and do 
    //nothing in else case.
}
```

This [thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12874/chaining-scheduled-apex-to-process-callouts-every-30-seconds) might help you as you can schedule some `Schedulable` class from your Batch which can invoke `future` methods.